# Can not get the array of data using Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to fetch data from mongoDB and store those in array format bot outside of callback function I am getting that array variable as blank using Node.js.

My code is below:

```
exports.getCardDetails=function(req,res){
    var userid=req.body.userid;
    var token_id=req.body.token_id;
    var userData=[];
    db.f_user_login.find({_id: mongoJs.ObjectId(userid),token:token_id},function(err,doc){
        if (doc.length > 0) {
            db.f_card_details.find({userid:userid},function(errs,docs){
                if (!errs) {
                    if (docs) {
                        for (var i = 0;i< docs.length;i++) {
                            var oemail=docs[i].email;
                            var id=docs[i]._id;
                            var name=docs[i].name;
                            var company=docs[i].company;
                            var position=docs[i].position;
                            var mobile=docs[i].mobile;
                            var landline=docs[i].landline;
                            var url=docs[i].url;
                            var postcode=docs[i].postcode;
                            var address=docs[i].address;
                            var isCurrentUser=docs[i].isCurrentUser;
                            db.f_user_profile.find({email:oemail},function(errs1,docs1){
                                if (!errs1) {
                                    if (docs1) {
                                        for(var j=0;j < docs1.length;j++){
                                            var profileText=docs1[j].profiletext;
                                            var biography=docs1[j].biography;
                                            var image=docs1[j].file;
                                            var profileid=docs1[j]._id;
                                        }
                                        var data={"id":id,"name":name,"company":company,"position":position,"mobile":mobile,"email":oemail,"landline":landline,"url":url,"postcode":postcode,"address":address,"profileText":profileText,"biography":biography,"image":image,"isCurrentUser":isCurrentUser,"profile_id":profileid};
                                        userData.push(data);
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        console.log('user',userData);
                        var sdata={"statusCode": 200,"data":userData ,"message": "Your card details has been fetched successfully"};
                        res.send(sdata);
                    }
                }
            })
        }else{
            var data={"statusCode": 404,"error": "Not Found","message":"Invalid User"};
            res.send(data);
        }
    })
}
```

Here I am pushing all data into `userData` array and trying to send those as response but here my problem is inside the loop all data are pushing to that array but `console.log('user',userData);` is showing blank while sending those data as response. I need to send those data as response.

Comment: This is making my eyes burn.  There's got to be a way you can simplify that query.  Chances are you'll find your problem during the refactor -- and spare the next person that may have to look at this function.

Comment: Also a hint: This is an asynchronous callback issue.  You are calling `res.send(sdata)` before the loop above it finishes (or even starts) executing.

Comment: yes, I solved it using the settimeout function.

Answer (score -1):

userData is filled in `db.f_user_profile.find` callback, that's where you should move `res.send(sdata);` as well. Also I suggest to convert to async/await if you are using node7:

```
exports.getCardDetails = async function(req,res){
    var userid=req.body.userid;
    var token_id=req.body.token_id;
    var userData=[];
    const user = await db.f_user_login.find({_id: mongoJs.ObjectId(userid),token:token_id}).next();
    if(user) {
      const cards = await db.f_card_details.find({userid:userid}).toArray();

      for (var i = 0;i < cards.length;i++) {
        var email=docs[i].email;
        var id=docs[i]._id;
        var name=docs[i].name;
        var company=docs[i].company;
        var position=docs[i].position;
        var mobile=docs[i].mobile;
        var landline=docs[i].landline;
        var url=docs[i].url;
        var postcode=docs[i].postcode;
        var address=docs[i].address;
        var isCurrentUser=docs[i].isCurrentUser;
        const profiles = await db.f_user_profile.find({email}).toArray();
        for(var j=0; j < profiles.length;j++) {
           var profileText=docs1[j].profiletext;
           var biography=docs1[j].biography;
           var image=docs1[j].file;
           var profile_id=docs1[j]._id;
           var data={id,name,company,position,mobile,email,landline,url,postcode,address,profileText,biography,image,isCurrentUser,profileid};
           userData.push(data)
        }
     }
     console.log('user',userData);
     var sdata={"statusCode": 200,"data":userData ,"message": "Your card details has been fetched successfully"};
     res.send(sdata);
   } else {
      var data={"statusCode": 404,"error": "Not Found","message":"Invalid User"};
      res.send(data);
   }
}
```